# How linker adds Program Headers to the Relocatable file?

Tags: linux, linker, ld, elf, readelf

So we know that `linker` (in my case `ld` ) adds the `Program Headers` to the `Relocatable file` while creating the actual `Executable`.

Then these Headers are used to load the program into memory at run-time.

- First of all how `ld` calculates and adds these headers to the file?
- And then if the `Program Headers` are used only to load the program into memory (correct me if I'm wrong), how come different executables have different number of `Program Headers`?

For example a simple helloworld written in assembly has **2 Program headers**:

```
readelf -h helloworld
...
  Number of program headers:         2
...
```

But the `bash` has **11 program headers**:

```
readelf -h /bin/bash
...
  Number of program headers:         11
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all how ld calculates and adds these headers to the file?

This question is too general to answer. You may wish to read [this series](https://lwn.net/Articles/276782/) of blogposts explaining how the linker works.

> And then if the Program Headers are used only to load the program into memory (correct me if I'm wrong), how come different executables have different number of Program Headers?

Executables have different number of Program Headers because they have different needs.

For example, a fully-static executable doesn't need any interaction with dynamic linker, and therefore doesn't need `PT_DYNAMIC` segment (and the program header that describes that segment).

Common dynamically linked executables will have at least two `PT_LOAD` segments (data and code), `PT_INTERP` (to tell which runtime loader to use), `PT_DYNAMIC` (to tell which shared libraries to use, and other info for `ld.so`), `PT_NOTE` (for linker build-id), and `PT_PHDR`. Each of these will have its own program header.